# Использования Service из другого приложения

Tags: android

Добрый день!
Я буду очень признателен, если Вы поможете мне найти ошибку в моём коде.
Есть два приложения.
Приложение1 имеет две кнопки, которые запускают и останавливают сервис из Приложения2.
Приложение1 не имеет Activity. Оно имеет только Java класс с сервисом.
Приложение1 запускается, но появляется ошибка при запуске одной из кнопок.
Если я правильно понимаю, то проблема с Intent.
Буду очень признателен за любые ответы комментарии по теме.

Приложение1 (Manifest)

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Приложение1 (Activity)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
intent = new Intent("com.example.timbook.myservice.MService");
}

public void onClickStart (View v) {
    startService(intent);
}

public void onClickStop (View v) {
    stopService(intent);
}
}
```

Приложение2 (Manifest)

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<service
    android:name="com.example.timbook.myservice.MService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.timbook.myservice.MService"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>

</service>
```

Приложение2 (Service)

```
public class MService extends Service{

MediaPlayer mp;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.glassanimals);
    mp.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Когда вы запускаете второе приложение сами, - оно запускается без ошибок? И что вам мешает сделать запуск service в приложении 1 и не делать отдельного приложения? Да и, в конце концов, - где лог ошибки?

Comment: Владимир, спасибо за комментарий.
Я прохожу курсы и задача была поставлена "Использовать сервис из отдельного приложения". Во втором приложении должен быть только Service и оно не должно иметь Activity.
Второе приложение не запускается, поскольку не имеет Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что не удавалось связать два проекта.
Решение выглядит следующим образом:

```
component = new ComponentName("com.example.macbook.project", "com.example.macbook.project.MyService");
explicitIntent = new Intent("com.example.macbook.project.MyService");
explicitIntent.setComponent(component);
```

В ComponentName указывается сначала **адрес проекта** и через запятую **полный путь к Service**.

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите обойтись вообще без Активити, то приложение нужно будить посылкой Broadcast intent'ом с флагом FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES.

Почитайте здесь:
http://ashimita.blogspot.com.by/2012/04/broadcast-receiver-change-in-flow-since.html?m=1

Можно также будить приложение через startService по Intent.

Comment: Владимир, если я Вас правильно понял, то я использовал второй предложенный Вами вариант startService. В Activity Приложения1 он запускается через onClick. При этом, приложение закрывается сразу при нажатии одной из кнопок.

Comment: @Tim стартуем Service из приложения 2 так: Intent intent=new Intent("имя action"); this.startService(intent);

Comment: А в приложении 1 нужно в манифесте в блок <service> добавить интент-фильтр: android:name=".StartClient"             android:enabled="true"             android:exported="true" >             <intent-filter><action android:name="имя action"></action>             </intent-filter>

Comment: к сожалению, не один из предложенных вариантов не помог решить ошибку программы. После того, как я найду ошибку, я оставлю сообщение с указанием ошибки в коде.